# Hibernate 4.x Logging Configuration

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-4.x, jboss-logging

I'm trying to find somthing about Hibernate 4.x logging configuration using jboss-logging, not log4j. Can anybody helps me? I need to disable info logging...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBoss logging seems to be a facade which delegates to an underlying logging framework. https://github.com/jboss-logging/jboss-logging/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jboss/logging/LoggerProviders.java has the source code for how jboss logging configures itself.

So you must figure out which underlying framework jboss-logging is using and based on that you can figure out what configuration options apply.

Answer (score 0):

Look in /standalone/configuration/standalone.xml (or as/domain/configuration/domain.xml) file. Search for . Hopefully you will see all the categories and their levels here. You should be able to modify the level here.

Answer (score -2):

Jboss has its own logging file. look for 'jboss-log4j.xml' you should control on hibernate from there. i think under conf.